# In Wso2 esb how to publish message using mqtt

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In wso2 esb how to publish the message using mqtt. I've added axis2-transport-mqtt-1.0.0.jar and mqtt-client-0.4.0.jar.

And for recieving i've configurred axis2.xml with

```
<transportReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mqtt.MqttListener" name="mqtt">
        <parameter locked="false" name="mqttConFactory">
                <parameter locked="false" name="mqtt.server.host.name">localhost</parameter>
                <parameter locked="false" name="mqtt.server.port">1883</parameter>
                <parameter locked="false" name="mqtt.client.id">esb.test.listener</parameter>
                <parameter locked="false" name="mqtt.topic.name">esb.test2</parameter>
        </parameter>
    </transportReceiver>
```

For publishing message i've configured axis2.xml like this.

But i'm not getting how to send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi as defined here https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+272%3APublishing+and+Subscribing+using+WSO2+ESB%27s+MQ+Telemetry+Transport

you have to create an endpoint with your mqtt server settings

```
<endpoint>
    <address uri="mqtt:/MyProxyName?mqtt.server.host.name=localhost&amp;mqtt.server.port=1883&amp;mqtt.client.id=esb.test.sender&amp;mqtt.topic.name=esb.test2&amp;mqtt.subscription.qos=2&amp;mqtt.blocking.sender=true"/>
</endpoint>
```

Change with your settings

**mqtt.server.host.name**: Hostname of the MQTT message broker.

**mqtt.server.port**:Port of server which clients can connect to. (1883 by default)

**mqtt.topic.name**: Topic name that ESB should be subscribe to

**mqtt.client.id**: This is used to identify ESB from broker side

then send your payload to this endpoint

Comment: In axis2.xml do I have to mention hostname, port, topic name or just in endpoint is enough

Comment: you have to define a transportSender (like mentioned in the doc)  <transportsender class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mqtt.MqttSender" name="mqtt">
</transportsender> in axis2.xml (transportReceiver is to listen to the queue, transportSender to push to the queue)

Comment: If I use API instaed of proxy server to call mqtt can i use MyAPIName instaed of MyProxyName

Comment: Yes I think you can put whatever you want there